# Chrome doesn't recognize console.log when it's called log

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, coffeescript

Like all programmers, I'm lazy. So in my `utils.js` there's a simple line:

```
window.log = console.log
```

This works fine in *firefox*, but it makes Chrome cry like a little boy. I have to write `console.log` to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `window.log = function(x) { console.log(x); };`

Comment: @nnnnnn: Almost. `console.log` is variadic and you're only paying attention to the first argument.

Comment: @muistooshort - That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer: at the time I didn't have time to write the full solution with `.apply()` and I knew somebody would call me on it. Plus I almost always use `console.log()` with a single argument so for my own use I probably wouldn't bother dealing with more. (I've upvoted your answer since you did write it all out.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chrome's `console.log` apparently pays attention to what `this` is so if you do this:

```
window.log = console.log
log('pancakes')
```

Then you'll get nothing more than a "TypeError: Illegal invocation" exception for your efforts. However, if you force the appropriate context thusly:

```
log.apply(console, 'pancakes')
```

then you'll get your `pancakes` in the console. That's why you need to wrap `console.log` in a function if you want to be lazy and just say `log`: some `console.log` implementations need to be called with the appropriate context.

However, just `window.log = (x) -> console.log(x)` is not quite correct as `console.log` is a variadic function. A better implementation would be this:

```
window.log = -> console.log.apply(console, arguments)
```

or to be pedantic, since `arguments` isn't an array and [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects an array, "cast" `arguments` to a real array in the usual way:

```
window.log = -> console.log.apply(console, Array::slice.call(arguments))
```

That should work the same everywhere and preserve the variadic nature of `console.log`. I doubt you need to be that pedantic though, just sending `arguments` in and pretending it is an array should be fine. You could also use [CoffeeScript splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) as a short form of the `[].slice` and `arguments` stuff:

```
window.log = (args...) -> console.log(args...)
```

If you look at the JavaScript version of that you'll see that it is the `slice` and `arguments` stuff in disguise.

Of course if you're using plain JavaScript, then one of these will work:

```
window.log = function() { console.log.apply(console, arguments) };
window.log = function() { console.log.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) };
```

Another option is to use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force `log` to be called in the context of `console`:

```
window.log = console.log.bind(console)
```

The downside is that not every browser supports `bind`.

Comment: Do you know if all browsers treat the `console` methods as JS functions that you can use `.apply()`, `.call()` or `.bind()` on? I had a vague idea there was at least one browser where that wouldn't work but I can't remember where I read that and I suspect I might be confusing it with something else like `alert()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera allow it. I don't feel like dragging my Windows box out of the dungeon (i.e. my closet) to check IE.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define window.log as a function that contains console.log

```
window.log = function(x) { console.log(x); }
```

Comment: I think this is more appropriate overall. It explicitly defines window.log as a function