# Why can't one set an alias to document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)
>   [Set document.getElementById to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804828/set-document-getelementbyid-to-variable)

Code would be more efficient if this was possible:

```
var min = document.getElementById;
```

and then call `document.getElementById()` using `min().`

Not trying to write minified code but in this particular case one can reduce scope lookup and shorten some lines.

Is this a syntax issue or a limiation on the language?

Comment: Can you use delegate function like `var min = function(inID){ return window.document.getElementById(inID); };`?

Comment: "Code would be more efficient"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `foo.bar()` then `this` is set to `foo` inside `bar`
When you copy `foo.bar` to `window.bar` then call `window.bar()`, `this` is set to `window`.

`getElementById` has to operate on a DOM document object.

Comment: `window` is the default object, it is the same question just making `window` explicit instead of looking up the scope chain.