# CommonJS Illegal invocation error when calling function on module.exports

Tags: javascript, commonjs, webpack, method-invocation

Doing this works fine:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

function _test() {
    console.log('hello from test');
}

requestAnimationFrame(_test);
```

However moving this to another file and exporting it using CommonJS/webpack results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

(like so:)

```
module.exports.requestAnimationFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
```

...

```
var poly = require('../utils/polyfills');
poly.requestAnimationFrame(_test);
```

It's probably super obvious but in my mind I don't get why that wouldn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Why are certain function calls termed "illegal invocations" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript)

It seems some native functions depend on context, so to fix this I bind to window:

```
module.exports.requestAnimationFrame = 
    (window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame).bind(window);
```