# Call a Javascript function stored in an object property

Tags: javascript

How come the code below doesn't work?

```js
var x = {};
x.a = alert;
x.a('asdf'); // TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: The alert function needs is calling context to be `window` so it can't be called with a different context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript

Comment: Agree on the duplication but I believe my example is clearer, as is the answer easier to read and understand. (I "knew" this q was posted but didn't find it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the internals of the `alert` function requires that the value of `this` be `window`.

```
x.a.call(window,'asdf');
```

… will work.

Comment: It looks like `window` can be replaced with `null` too(!)

Comment: Can you explain it more.

Comment: `x.a.call(null, 'asdf');` works.