# Delay all ajax requests

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

I'm having this error when trying delay all ajax requests in my application.

```
(function(send) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
    setTimeout( function () {
      send.call(this, data); //Error here
    },3000);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Could you give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, here, `this` will refer to **setTimeout** function

Comment: How can i change that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are certain function calls termed "illegal invocations" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript)

Comment: @fluis save it into a variable like: `var _this = this` before calling `setTimeout`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are calling `.call` passing in the current scope which would be `window`.

```
(function(send) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout( function () {
      send.call(self, data); //Updated `this` context
    },3000);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Comment: _"which would be setTimeout function"_ No -> `this === window`