# How can I convert string to internal code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This came when I tried to figure how jQuery works. How can I declare a string and then convert it such that it becomes readable by machine. In short, how can I place the string without the quotes so that the string parses to `document.querySelector` and then I add my brackets with the selector. Before, I had `eval(S)(.wrapper).className = "red";`

I basically want to achieve what is commented and here is the relevant code:

```js
const S = "document.querySelector";
S(".wrapper").className = "red"; 

/* Below is how I want the final result as. */
/* document.querySelector(".wrapper").className = "red" */
```

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50;
    left: 50;
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dom.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Dom.js</h1>
        <p>Making Dom Manipulation Easier!</p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to make it a string.  `var S = document.querySelector;` would allow you to use S in the place of that method through out the code where that variable is scoped.  Not sure why you would do this though as it makes the code less clear.

Comment: 11 times out of 10, when someone wants to know how to convert a string to executable code, the solution is to think about the problem differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function that returns `document.querySelector(selector)`

```js
const S = (selector) => {
  return document.querySelector(selector)
}

// or 
/*
const S = function(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector)
}
*/

S(".wrapper").className = "red";
```

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50;
  left: 50;
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Dom.js</h1>
  <p>Making Dom Manipulation Easier!</p>
</div>
```

or, as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript) , not to use a function and keep the context, use `bind`

```js
var S = document.querySelector.bind(document)

S(".wrapper").className = "red";
```

```css
html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50;
  left: 50;
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Dom.js</h1>
  <p>Making Dom Manipulation Easier!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this, but there is literally no point to doing this.  Just assigning the method to the variable achieves the same result, with one less method defined.

Comment: @Taplar totally agree with you, but if i understand correctly, that's what the question is about .. just to evoid `eval()`

Comment: Avoiding the eval() doesn't mean you have to use an arrow function.

Comment: @Taplar yes you don't have to it's just one way ,

Comment: @Taplar , assigning the method to the variable doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/5gcpjh54/14/

Comment: That's really weird, i'm not sure why it's erroring.

Comment: @Taplar see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript

Comment: Ahhh.  https://jsfiddle.net/5gcpjh54/24/  So to not use the arrow method, you'd have to bind the document to it so the context still exists.  Guess that makes sense.  Which bind() also creates a new method so, *shrug*, not saving anything arrow method vs bind

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was looking for!