# TypeError: Failed to execute 'update' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a VueJS app created using the CLI as a PWA. My service worker file looked like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' +
          'For more details, visit https://<google-link>'
      )
    },
    registered(registration) {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
      setInterval(registration.update, 1000 * 60 * 60)
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated(registration) {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration }))
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

I was getting a `TypeError: Failed to execute 'update' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': Illegal invocation` error in `setInterval` when `registration.update` was called. This interval checks every hour if there are any updates to the web app.  I searched everywhere and could not find what was causing this issue, so I'm creating this to help anyone else out who might experience the same issue.

Comment: @user202729 Done.  The only backtrace I was getting from Airbrake was the error itself.  I haven't found front-end backtraces very helpful due to minification and the way it's being chunked.

Comment: Okay, there have been several questions about `Illegal invocation` (each one manifest itself in different ways) -- however when I put into Startpage (Google proxy, kind of) the *whole* error message it points to the correct one, so this question might not be that useful -- anyway see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript) for more info about function context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by wrapping `registration.update` in a function:

```
 registered(registration) {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Checking for service worker update.')
        registration.update()
      }, 1000 * 60 * 60)
    },
```

Credit to this page for helping me figure that out: https://www.kaels-kabbage.com/post/service-worker-updates/