# 'Illegal invocation' using input setCustomValidity and TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty much new to Typescript world and am converting one of the first React applications.

Here I'm trying to set custom messages on input validation by using `event.target.setCustomValidity` but I'm getting the 'Illegal invocation' error when the setCustomValidity function gets triggered.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-pike-snw1q?file=/src/Input.tsx) there is the sandbox; To trigger the error it's just required to update the first input.

Debugging the error, I'd think the issue stands on the declared type of `event.target` set `as HTMLInputElement`, or on the declared type of `event` set as a `React.SyntheticEvent`; Perhaps I'm using the wrong types for the event which doesn't always have a setCustomValidity function?

To premise the code used on the sandbox works perfectly fine without Typescript

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you in advance for your help!

**Components code**

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // Check if value entered is a valid email. Ref: http://emailregex.com/
  const emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/;

  const initialForm = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);

  // Listen to form inputs and updates form state respectively
  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    const {
      name,
      value,
      type,
      setCustomValidity
    } = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });

    if (type === "email" && !emailPattern.test(value)) {
      setCustomValidity("Please select a valid email address.");
    } else {
      setCustomValidity("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input
        id="username"
        type="string"
        name="username"
        label="username"
        value={form["username"]}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required={true}
      />
      <Input
        id="password"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        label="password"
        value={form["password"]}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Input.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

type PropsType = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
  value: string;
  label: string;
  onChange: (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => void;
  required: boolean;
};

/**
 * Reusable standard Input component.
 * @param {Object} props - Props passed from parent component containing input attributes.
 * @return - Controlled input element.
 */
const Input: React.FC<PropsType> = ({
  id,
  type,
  label,
  onChange,
  required,
  ...rest
}: PropsType) => (
  <div className="input">
    <input
      id={id}
      type={type}
      placeholder=""
      {...rest}
      onChange={(event) => onChange(event)}
      minLength={type === "password" ? 8 : undefined}
    />
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {label}
      {required && " *"}
    </label>
  </div>
);

export default Input;
```

Comment: Type declarations do not impact runtime behavior.

Comment: The problem is the use of destructuring to get the `setCustomValidity` function. If you replace it with `event.target.setCustomValidity("");` it works fine. If so, this is likely a duplicate of [Why are certain function calls termed “illegal invocations” in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10743596/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for pointing out; That was what I first implemented, but I had to update as I was getting ts errors: Property 'setCustomValidity' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339) - How could I go around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Heretic Monkey pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566384/illegal-invocation-using-input-setcustomvalidity-and-ts#comment115923135_65566384), you should use `event.target.setCustomValidity` rather than destructuring the method to avoid losing the context of the function when it's called. See [Why are certain function calls termed "illegal invocations" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript).

Then, to properly type the event you may want to start by changing the `onChange` typing in `Input.tsx`.

```js
// src/Input.tsx
type PropsType = {
    //...
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
};
```

Then update your `handleChange` callback accordingly in `App.tsx`.

```js
// src/App.tsx
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    //...
    if (type === "email" && !emailPattern.test(value)) {
        event.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a valid email address.");
    } else {
        event.target.setCustomValidity("");
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason why we should like this `event.target.setCustomValidity` instead of destructuring?

Comment: @Rajiv There is, to avoid losing the context of the function when it's called. See [Why are certain function calls termed "illegal invocations" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript). I've updated my answer with the clarification.