# Problem with accessing a property on the prototype of document.createElement("a")

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to write a custom JavaScript console for use at school where they block inspect, and I've gotten quite far, but my stringify method throws an error when I try to crawl an HTMLAnchorElement. I've narrowed it down to an `Illegal invocation` for trying to access properties of the prototype of `document.createElement("a")`.

```js
const x = document.createElement("a");
const y = Object.getPrototypeOf(x);
console.log(y["href"]);
```

This code throws the `Illegal invocation`. However, this

```js
const y = HTMLAnchorElement;
console.log(y["href"]);
```

doesn't. I've looked into the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("a")), "href").get()` and that seems to be the problem. Is there a fix (perhaps binding the `this` value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example it does not throw an exception because `HTMLAnchorElement` is a constructor, (thus a function), and functions don't have a propery `"href"` thus this is undefined. On the first and third example you get an Illegal invocation error because as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743596/why-are-certain-function-calls-termed-illegal-invocations-in-javascript) the context is lost. You can look the link for more detail, but in short, as you probably suspected the function internally uses this, so when its called outside of the context, it throws an error.

> Is there a fix (perhaps binding the `this` value)?

Yes, you can fix it binding the right context to it

For example in your third example `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement("a")), "href").get()` the get seems to expect the element that was created as context, thus this works:

```
let href = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(a = document.createElement("a")), "href").get.bind(a); // note that I set a to the newly created element and then binded it to the get function
href() // no error, its an empty string as expected
```

but its not always clear what is the expected context, so I don't know what you are trying to acomplish but maybe its not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

> However, this
>
> ```
> const y = HTMLAnchorElement;
> console.log(y["href"]);
> ```
>
> doesn’t.

Because you’re looking for `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype`. `HTMLAnchorElement["href"]` just doesn’t exist.

> Is there a fix (perhaps binding the `this` value)?

Yes, which is done by accessing the `href` property via the element itself, i.e. `x["href"]`.