# JavaScript - refactor getElementById

Tags: javascript, refactoring, getelementbyid

I use alot of getElementById and I have a question about what is the best way to refactor it.

As many already did, I use this code to make it simpler, easier and to reduce the file size:

```
    function $(id){
return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

But over to what I need help with: is it better to add a variable with the `document.getElementById` and just change them in every function I need it? Or, should I just stick to what I already have (the usage of `$(id)`)

Comment: What does "add a variable with the document.getElementById" mean?

Comment: I'm with @Quentin. I don't understand half your question. Also, I'd call your function `$id` instead of `$` so you don't have naming collisions with any of the popular libraries.

Comment: And "Oh no, not another wretched `$` function", there are too many of them, and [it isn't clear what any of them do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting). If typing `document.getElementById` is that much effort, write a macro for your editor instead of a mysterious symbol that other maintainers of your code will have to interpret.

Comment: If you want to reduce the file size, use something like closure compiler in your build process.

Comment: @Quentin I have no idea of what you are talking about. I am not using any JavaScript Librarys. Explain to me if you want.

Comment: [The Closure Compiler is a tool for making JavaScript download and run faster. It is a true compiler for JavaScript](https://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=closure+compiler)

Comment: Thanks. I used `_` instead of `$` because it looks like C++ and has minor collison problems with others. What do you think of that?

Comment: I think it has exactly the same problem as `$`. It doesn't tell the maintainer what it does and it collides with a reasonably popular [general purpose library](http://underscorejs.org/).

Comment: I am not going to use a JavaScript library, so I am guessing that is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `window.$ = document.getElementById.bind(document);` will also work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804995/1048572) and [Javascript Shorthand for getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6398787/1048572) in general.

If you are afraid of polluting the global namespace or conflicting with certain libraries that use the `$` selector shortcut extensively (and especially their plugins), you need to make it local variable in your function's scope:

```
(function(/*id selector*/ $) {
    // your code here, using $
})(document.getElementById.bind(document));
```

is effectively the same as

```
(function() {
    function $(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
    // your code here, using $
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not use jQuery because it feels better to use plain JavaScript and just learn and do it the little less efficient way.

Comment: I did not say anything of jQuery :-) Also, plain JavaScript is the *much more* efficient way than usage of heavy libraries...

Comment: Now I know that! Would rank your answer up, but I do not have enough points yet :(

Comment: Well, "accepted answer" is good enough! Thank you for everything!