# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome doesn’t recognize console.log when it’s called log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612398/chrome-doesnt-recognize-console-log-when-its-called-log)

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work when I set the method to `console.log`?

```
var met = "console.log";
var msg = "HELLO WORLD";
var n = met.split(".");
var f = this;
$.each(n, function(k, v){
    f = f[v];
});
f(msg);
```

this seems to work when I tried using `alert`

Comment: your code perfectly runs..! i can run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
var met = "console.log";
var msg = "HELLO WORLD";
var n = met.split(".");
var tail = n.pop();
var f = this;
$.each(n, function(k, v){
    f = f[v];
});
var func = function(){ f[tail].apply(f, arguments); }
func(msg);
```

Tested this working on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari. Doesn't seem to work on IE9.

I got the ideas from @muistooshort on [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612398/chrome-doesnt-recognize-console-log-when-its-called-log)
and also from @jasonbunting on [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the log function of console gets assigned to the `f` variable, but when executed it has no reference to the console scope anymore.  Javascript scoping can get tricky when dealing with callbacks or passing functions around.

As far as @Murali's comment that it works, some browsers implement the console.log method differently than others.

As an experiment, try running this code and see if it works:

```
var met = "console.log";
var msg = "HELLO WORLD";
var n = met.split(".");
n[1].call(n[0], msg);
```

Using the `.call` method lets you execute a function and declare its' scope.  If that works for you, it should be easy to refactor your loop scenario.