# Passing anonymous vars in While loop syntax

Tags: coffeescript, while-loop

Im just starting with Coffeescript and running the examples presented in "Programming in CoffeeScript book".

In the while loops section i got intrigued why the call to the times function has to declared as stated bellow.

```
times = (number_of_times, callback) ->
    index = 0
    while index++ < number_of_times
        callback(index)
    return null

times 5, (index) ->
    console.log index
```

I was struggling a bit to read the code and when i've tried:

```
times (5, (index)) ->
   console.log index
```

It returns an error.
Could you provide some help understanding this code please?

Comment: Please attach the error message you mentioned in your post.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please fix the indent too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard function definition is structured like this:

```
name = (arg, ...) ->
    body
```

so there's not much to say about your `times` definition. So let us look at your call to `times`:

```
times 5, (index) ->
    console.log index
```

This part:

```
(index) ->
    console.log index
```

is just another function definition but this one is anonymous. We can rewrite your call using a named function to help clarify things:

```
f = (index) -> console.log index
times 5, f
```

And we can fill in the optional parentheses to really spell it out:

```
f = (index) -> console.log(index)
times(5, f)
```

Once everything has been broken down you should see that the `5` and `(index)` in:

```
times 5, (index) ->
   console.log index
```

have nothing to do with each other so grouping them in parentheses:

```
times (5, (index)) ->
   console.log index
```

doesn't make sense. If you wanted to add parentheses to that `times` call to clarify the structure (which is quite useful when the callback function is longer) you need to know two things:

1. No space between the function name and the opening parenthesis around the arguments. If there is a space then CoffeeScript will think you're using the parentheses to group things *within* the argument list.
2. The parentheses need to surround the entire argument list and that includes the callback function's body.

Give that, you'd write:

```
times(5, (index) ->
   console.log index
)
```

or perhaps:

```
times(5, (index) -> console.log(index))
```

With `console.log` was a non-native function you could even:

```
times(5, console.log)
```

but that will give you a [`TypeError` in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612657/479863) so don't go that far.